# 2 <hr> on the same line

Tags: html, css

im pretty new to css and html and i've been trying some things for a small school project. I currently have 2 vertical lines and like this.

```
<hr class="topline" width=58% size=3 NOSHADE>            
<hr class="verticalline" width=0.15% size=1000 NOSHADE>
```

I have some css that pushes the vertical line all the way to the left so i have like a visible margin for some styling. But even when it is to the left of the above line, it doesnt push itself up.

[image]

I want that left line to be pushed up the side to the top so it is along side the horizontal one. Can someone help?

Comment: If you'd like to add a border to something, I'd recommend just adding a border. Horizontal rules have very limited functionality.

Comment: You should use a border on an element, [something like this example is pretty straight forward](http://jsbin.com/hisaye/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, that's a default style of line. The solution is adding a style margin-top with minus value of it (meaning of invers).

Try this :

```
<hr style="margin-left:0px;" class="topline" width="58%" size="3" NOSHADE>
<hr style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:-10px" class="verticalline" width="0.15%" size="1000" NOSHADE>
```

Remove the `margin-left:0px;` from style if you want it to be centered.